# iPhone 4S iOS 7 deletes music by itself

Tags: ios, itunes, iphone, music

My iPhone 4S (currently running iOS 7) seems to delete music by itself, if storage is getting low.

The music has not been purchased in the iTunes store and it was manually copied to my phone.

Is there a solution to stop this, respectively which settings on my phone/iTunes are necessary (without changing iOS-version)?

Thank's for the help.

Comment: Do you by any chance have Apple Music enabled.

Comment: If it were me, I'd just save myself a lot of trouble and update to iOS 9.

Comment: @bassplayer7 no i don't think so, could this be a possible cause?

Comment: @RedEagle2000 with an 8gb Iphone 4s you should never do so ;) (beside the bugs and performance reduction - never change a running system)

Comment: @scherzkraperl I don't know about that. iOS 9 is supposed to increase the performance and battery life of all iOS devices, even older ones, and fix many, many bugs. If you're not comfortable with updating, that's fine, but if it were me I'd definitely update my own iPhone 4S.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 1. never change a running system, even as programming beginner.
2. iOS9 is made for bigger smartphones (e.g. iphone6), causing different style and performance problems (i don't want to wait for seconds while multitasking).
3. this discussion is getting off topic :) my questions presumes not changing iOS

Comment: Yes. I would absolutely suspect Apple Music if it was enabled on your phone. Since it isn't, I wouldn't suspect that as the problem.

Comment: @bassplayer7 could it be possible that this function is only turned on in iTunes (I've never informed myself about Apple Music)? I like your exclusion method :)

Comment: No. I realized that you can't have Apple Music on your iPhone because you are on iOS 7 - and you are very fortunate. The Music app was sacrificed on the altar of Apple Music.

Comment: Ok, let's assume we can exclude Apple Music. Do you think that there could be some kind of iTunes bug?